# Refreshing an adapter every time I get back to an activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-adapter

I've got two activities holding 2 GridViews each. One in each activity is clickable and the other (with no onItemClick defined) should get notified about clicks in the other activity's clickable one and do actions accordingly(using global variables). When transferring between those two activities I am not allowed to finish them so the Clickable one saves state(though if I do finish them the non-clickable one works because the adapter refreshes in onCreate).

How can I refresh my adapter every time I get back to non-finished activity?

Comment: yourview.setAdapter(adapter); call in onResume method inside as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

override this method in your activity.

```
@Override
 public void onResume(){
 super.onResume();
// refresh your adapter here.
}
```

This methods will be called when your first activity resumes. more can be found [HERE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Answer (score 0):

use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); in onResume method of activity